# Deploy python REST service on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, ubuntu-16.04

I have started learning django and Python.

I have developed one service using Visual Studio Code on my Windows machine.

It is working as expected on Windows machine.

Now I want to deploy the same on a Ubuntu server. (But failing as there is no 'bin' folder inside virtual environment)

How can I do it? I know I am missing something basic here.

Could you please help/ point me where I can read about it?

Comment: Can you add more details? Is it your own server on your own network? Is it a cloud server? If so, which one? How are you trying to install it?

Comment: I tried running the 'runserver' in the similar fashion on Ubuntu after 'activate'. My main problem is, there doesn't exist python command or exists 'python.exe' inside venv which is not executable on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do I need to build in some other way to make it working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you are deploying your application at path /opt/.
Follow the below steps to deploy:

1. To get started we need to install some packages, run the following commands:

   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev ufw virtualenv
     Above command would install the basics python dev packages on ubuntu server.
2. Create a virtualenv at some path of your choice(might be at /opt/.env), following commands:

   - virtualenv .env
   - Activate the environment: source .env/bin/activate
3. Install all requirement packages in virtual-env that you require to run your Django application.
4. Test your service manually by running: python manage.py runserver (this would shows that all dependencies are installed)
5. After that, You can install the web server gateway i.e Gunicorn and Supervisor as process monitoring tool for your service. Please refer: http://rahmonov.me/posts/run-a-django-app-with-nginx-gunicorn-and-supervisor/
6. Nginx can be run on server as web server for routing request to your application port/socket file.

Above are the high level steps to deploy the Django Application.